# Inno Setup: Custom classes

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Does Inno Setup allow to create own classes after 'type' keyword?
I've tried to inherit from TBitmapImage:

```
[Code]
type
    TBitmapButton = class(TBitmapImage)
        property OnHoverImage: TAlphaBitmap;
        procedure Hovering(IsHovered: Boolean);
    end;
```

But compiler said that 'Identifier expected' in the begining of class declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the short answer to your question is **no**. According to this help topic on the **InnoSetup** website about a similar matter:

http://news.jrsoftware.org/news/innosetup.code/msg25634.html

It says in part:

> RemObjects Pascal doesn't support custom ([Code] created) classes.

So I don't think you can do what you are desiring. The above discussion thread mentions a possible **workaround**:

> You can define a "record" containing all of the desired fields, and an
> "array of" your record type to create a dynamically-expandable indexed
> list of them.
>
> You can't define methods or constructors/destructors directly attached
> to these, but you can define loose procedures/functions that do the
> equivalent.
>
> That's as close to custom classes as you're going to get in ROPS.

I do not know if that will be sufficient for your needs.

If you need to research **InnoSetup** code functionality there is a great resource here:

http://www.jrsoftware.org/newsgroups.php#search